# can i delay http response header after i run the page?

Tags: javascript, http

so i have a function like this

```
 public ActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "180");
            return View();
        }
```

so i want to when i open something in that dashboard, ex a popup:

```
    $scope.openpopup = function (id) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: "stuff/Popupstuff/?id=" + id, 
            size: '',
        });
        $cookieStore.put("id",id);
        modalInstance.result.finally(function () {
            $cookieStore.remove("id");
        });
    }
```

i want to make the refresh to stop/delay until i close the popup, is that possible?

Comment: rethink how you will fetch the fresh dashboard data (its common to use ajax/xhr) rather than adding a global refresh header in the first place

Comment: hmmm i will think about that more, thanks for the comment

Comment: other than using a header you could use `const timer = setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), 180000)` then clear / reset it etc, or make it maintainable with some global helper https://playcode.io/1049592 or better to use ajax to refresh data, its intrusive/ugly ux to constantly reload the page

Comment: hmmm you just give me a ideal to try, i really appriciate it, i'll try it, thanks alot

Comment: @XuanTungDang try this if needed not sure if its useful for you or not,
https://dev.to/codever/how-to-delay-an-http-response-in-expressjs-4dpb

Comment: @Enthusiasticcoder i got the answer for the solution, but still thank you for answering it, i appriciate it